# Why use generic constraints in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I've read an excellent article on MSDN regarding Generics in C#.

The question that popped in my head was - why should i be using generic constraints?

For example, if I use code like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : ISomething
{
}
```

can't I switch ALL references of `T` in this class with `ISomething`?

What's the benefit of using this approach?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You ask, "can't I switch ALL references of `T` in this class with `ISomething`?"  So I think you mean to compare:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : ISomething 
{ 
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

With:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public ISomething MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In the second example, `MyProperty` is only guaranteed to be an instance of `ISomething`.  In the first example, `MyProperty` is whatever `T` is, even if that is a specific subtype of `ISomething`.  Consider a concrete implementation of `ISomething`:

```
public class MySomething : ISomething
{
    public string MyOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if we use the first, generic, example, we could have:

```
MyClass<MySomething> myClass = new MyClass<MySomething>();
Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty.MyOtherProperty);
```

On the other hand, if we used the second example, we wouldn't be able to access `MyOtherProperty` since it's only known to be an `ISomething`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty.MyOtherProperty); // Won't compile, no property "MyOtherProperty"
```

On a different note, the reason these type constraints are useful is that you can refer to `MyProperty` (type `T`) and access members of `ISomething`.  In other words, if `ISomething` were declared like:

```
public interface ISomething 
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could access `MyProperty.SomeProperty`.  If you omitted the `where T : ISomething` then you wouldn't be able to access `SomeProperty` since `T` would only be known to be of type `object`.

Answer (score 8):

Type Safety. For example, suppose you're creating a container. You can pass in something to that container and retrieve it in the proper form without having to do any casts later by parameterizing the container. You're simply defining constraints on the types of things that you're willing to store in your container.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of the difference, by just using `List<>`

Image list wouldn't be generic but it would just use `IListElement` everywhere it used the generic instead. Now Imagine you have an object that's something like this.

```
class Element : IListElement
{
   public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

now I could just do `list.Add(element);` and there wouldn't be a difference with a real `List<Element>`. However when I retreive data it's a different story, if I use the list that uses `IListElement` then I have to cast my data back so I can get the `Something` out of it. Thus i'd have to do:

```
string s = ((Element)list[0]).Something;
```

while with the generic I can just do:

```
string s = list[0].Something;
```

saves a lot of trouble, ofcourse it goes a bit further than that but I think you can get the idea from this.

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start, you can call methods defined in ISomething within the code for the generic method / methods on the generic class.  If T was allowed to be any type then this would not be possible (although you could always do some runtime casting).

So it allows you to enforce compile-time constraints on what T can be and therefore rely on these constraints when you write the code - turning runtime errors into compile time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use ISomething in place of T , but that will manually ***close*** the generic type to an ordinary class. It wont be a generic type any more. By using T, you keep the type ***open*** to as many ISomething subtypes as you want. **Code reuse without compromising type safety is the key benefit here.** For example if you use a Stack of ISomethings, you can push any ISomething  onto the stack but a pop has to occur with a downcast to the actual subtype of ISomething for it to be useful. Downcasting creates a potential failure point, which will not be there in a generic `Stack<T>` where T:ISomething

Answer (score 1):

Consumer of your class gets the benefit of increased type-safety, among others.

```
class Widget : IPokable { }

// No generics
Widget w = (Widget)list[0]; // cast can fail

// With generics
Widget w = list[0];
```

Without generics, if list was containing `IPokable` objects, **cast is still necessary**.

Class you're implementing gets the benefit of using specific methods on the generic object.

```
class PokableList<T> where T : IPokable {
    public T PokeAndGet() {
        currentObj.Poke();
        return currentObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple example might help.

If I have these classes:

```
public class ListOfCars<T> : List<T> where T : Car { }

public abstract class Car { }
public class Porsche : Car { }
public class Bmw : Car { }
```

...and then if I write this code:

```
var porsches = new ListOfCars<Porsche>();

// OK
porsches.Add(new Porsche());

//Error - Can't add BMW's to Porsche List
porsches.Add(new Bmw());
```

You can see that I can't add a BMW to a Porsche list, but if I just programmed off of the base class it would be allowed.