# Using where in an interface declaration

Tags: c#, generics, repository

I have the following domain object:

```
public class Bank : IEntity
{
}
```

And the following IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
}
```

Is the `where TEntity : IEntity` needed?  What does this mean, that TEntity is of type IEntity?  Is there any naming conventions when I use something like TEntity?  What does the T stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IRepository` is a generic class and the `TEntity` is the generic type parameter. It's like a placeholder for the actual type.

`TEntity: IEntity` means that you will require that the actual type being used implements `IEntity` and in your actual repository implementation you can refer to methods and properties exposed by the interface `IEntity`.

Whether or not it is needed depends on the intended usage of the repository. Usually type restrictions are used to enforce certain properties of the types being used on which the implementation of the generic relies on.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about generic constraints and their use in [Why use generic constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073852/why-use-generic-constraints-in-c), and you might want to check out the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more official coverage.

As to the 'T', that's strictly a convention that harks back to C++ when such things were called '[templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29)'.  (It is a convention that you should follow, however.)

Answer (score 1):

`where TEntity : IEntity` means that the `TEntity` type has to implement `IEntity` interface. Saying in other words in your generic interface `IRepository` you can use types that implements `IEntity` interface.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your design time needs.

You can replace generic `TEntity` uses with `IEntity`. But, then you will be restricted to members of `IEntity` only.

You will have to cast `IEntity` members to get access to its child type members.