# Java to C#: Extends in Generic

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to convert this Java (Android) code to c# (MonoDroid) but I don't understand the `<Item extends OverlayItem>`

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<Item extends OverlayItem> extends FrameLayout
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's adding a constraint to the type parameter.  It's analogous to the `where` clause in C#.

In Java, you have:

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<Item extends OverlayItem> extends FrameLayout
```

Where `Item` is a type parameter that must subclass or implement type `OverlayItem`.  In C# this would be written as:

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<Item> : FrameLayout where Item : OverlayItem
```

You can see how the constraint is moved to the end, but otherwise analogous.  It is very much [common practice in C# to name type parameters prefixed with a `T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182243.aspx), so I would recommend the name `TItem` like so:

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<TItem> : FrameLayout where TItem : OverlayItem
```

This helps make clear the pretty important distinction between type parameters and ordinary types.

For a discussion on when you'd want to use type constraints like this, [I go into this at length in a previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073852/why-use-generic-constraints-in-c-sharp/4073899#4073899)

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as this:

```
public class BalloonOverlayView<Item> : FrameLayout where Item : OverlayItem
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the parametrised type `Item` has to be a subclass of `OverlayItem`

Semantically, this implies that it makes to no sense to instantiate BalloonOverlayView with a parameterised type if it does not extend `OverlayItem`