# What is the goal of Where in c#?

Tags: c#

i have this code:

```
Task NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelInteres;
```

i dont understand the goal of where, what is the goal?, 
can someone explain to me what it is for, Is it mandatory to use the reserved word WHERE?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use generic constraints in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073852/why-use-generic-constraints-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory at all. You would use `where` when you want to apply a constraint on the types of your generics.

Some examples:

```
class MyGeneric<T> where T : class  {...}
```

`T` here can only be a class (no structs, like `int`, `byte` etc.), this makes it possible to handle better nullable types, for example.

```
class MyGeneric<T> where T : notnull {...}
```

`T` can be struct or class, but will never be null.

```
class MyGeneric<T> where T : new() {...}
```

`T` is a class that can be instantiated with an empty constructor. Useful if you want to have generic fabrics.

```
interface Animal { public int nrPaws {get;} }
class MyGeneric<T> where T : Animal {...}
```

`T` must implement the interface `Animal`. In this way you can control the methods you can call from `MyGeneric`.

---

`where` is generally very handy when you want these kind of checks to be done at compile-time rather that throwing error during run-time.

Answer (score -1):

it constrains what types can be used for `TViewModel`

Comment: can i help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621436/how-use-the-styles-merged please