# How use the styles merged?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I use merged styles? I am merging in application file then I want to use it on another screen, but I don't find the style, what is my wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns=...
                    x:Class="CodeFabric.ExpenseTracker.Mobile.Forms.Styles.EntryStyle">

    <Style x:Key="highlightedLabel" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGreen" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am merging here: until here all is working fine

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="local:EntryStyle"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

but when I am using the style here, the style isn't found. Why?

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource highlightedLabel}" Text="I'm Highlighted" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'MergedWith' property is obsolete now, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.resourcedictionary.mergedwith?view=xamarin-forms

Basically, you can use merged dictionaries with a standalone resource file like this:

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResourceDictionaryDemo">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <local:MyResourceDictionary />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    ...
</Application>
```

More usage please refer to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merged-resource-dictionaries)

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how i can use in a control? <Label Style="{StaticResource highlightedLabel}" Text="I'm Highlighted" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:EntryStyle />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

hope this helps.-

Comment: but how i can use in a control? <Label Style="{StaticResource highlightedLabel}" Text="I'm Highlighted" />

Comment: Yes, you would use it like any other Resource. The above code will merge all the resources in a single file at compile time.