# Why use a generic type and then limit it to one type with "where"?

Tags: c#, .net

What's the advantage of using this:

```cs
DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : DataRow
```

where you can just do this:

```cs
DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this DataRow[] source)
```

Excuse me if this is a dumb question, I'm new at this

Comment: That code would make sense when using typed datatables/datarows. Check [Typed vs. untyped datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/typed-vs-untyped-datasets?view=vs-2019). Do note that the equivalent would be `this IEnumarable<DataRow> source`

Comment: But that would also inherit from DataRow right? @Cleptus

Comment: Yeah, both would work similar, the difference would be if you want to add the functionality to the type (the extension method) or not. Pretty much depends on your scenario and your liking.

Comment: Accepting `IEnumerable<T>` is more general than accepting an array. I think we'd have to see the body of the method to see whether it's doing anything which is enabled by generics, but not by an array

Comment: Also bear in mind that an `IEnumerable` typically involves a cursor, not the actual data set. Imagine a multi-million records data source. If you write the copy requiring an array, then will be problematic to istantiate such as array. Instead, the cursor permits to scan an arbitrary-size collection without loading anything more than a single record.

Comment: All valid remarks about the array and IEnumerable. But the question is about T vs DataRow. In this case it would be `DataTable CopyToDataTable(this IEnumerable<DataRow> source)` as @Cleptus suggested.

Comment: @canton7 I think I did not find anything enabled by the Generic. It even typed it back to a DataRow inside. Line 148-151. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataTableExtensions.cs,f13583ec86a5fe61

Comment: So, there's an advantage in taking an `IEnumerable` rather than an array: what if the caller has a list rather than array, or something else which is an `IEnumerable` but not an array. The input doesn't *need* to be an array, it just needs to be enumerable, so accepting an `IEnumerable` is more flexible. I think it could happily take an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` due to covariance, but that was only introduced in C#4, and it's quite possible that this code predates that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68619005/259769

Comment: @Enigmativity That doesn't answer this specific case, however. We're not adding to a collection of `T`, just a collection of `DataRow`

Comment: @Enigmativity This question is not a dupe of the one you've linked to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two parts to this.

The first is that accepting an `IEnumerable` is more flexible than accepting an array. What if the user has a `List<DataRow>`, or some other collection type? What if they want to pass the result of a linq query? Accepting an array forces them to allocate a new array just to pass to `CopyToDataTable`, and that's unnecessary cost.

There's no reason why `CopyToDataTable` needs an array: it just needs an `IEnumerable`. So it's best if it just accepts an `IEnumerable`.

That said, due to [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) it would be possible to use the signature:

```
DataTable CopyToDataTable(this IEnumerable<DataRow> source)
```

... and users would be able to pass e.g. an `IEnumerable<TableDetailsRow>` (where `TableDetailsRow` extends `DataRow`). However, covariance was only introduced in C# 4, and [that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=net-5.0) has been around since .NET 3.5, which means it was probably written in C# 3. Since covariance wasn't available then, generics was the next best thing.

Comment: Excellent answer. Very probable. Upvoted.

Comment: oh, your answer is straight to the point. So `IEnumerable<T>` is used so it can be used for any kind of collection that implements IEnumerable, not just `T[]` or whatever. Thanks :)